# Set Custom Drawable Background of Material Chip Programetically

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, material-design, android-chips

I want help. I want UI as below and I am using Material Chip for that.

[image]

These are material chip of filter type.

But the tricky part is these all chips get added in view dynamically (Based on API response, adding programmatically). So how can I set custom drawable for selected chips and unselected chips programmatically?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: You can use a `GradientDrawable` for dynamically generating drawables based on your custom colours & gradient direction.

Comment: @DarShan Chip cannot contain the background of drawable type. So we have to give backgroundColor, not any kind of drawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to find every possible solution and after reading all documents and answers came to the conclusion that It is **NOT** possible to give gradient background to Material Chip as this functionality is not provided by the material library itself.

Simply taking a rounded button and then customizing background will be an easy solution for me and fulfill my requirements.